# Prevent concurrent sessions in Grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to prevent the concurrent sessions for the user in my application , It was developed using `Grails 3.3.10` and `Spring Security 4 grails plugin` for example user `A` logged into the system from `Chrome` and tried to login to the system from `Internet explore` using same the username, I want to prevent this action so the username got has one active session only. I can't find anything in the plugin's configurations may achieve this.

Comment: You want to prevent 2nd login and continue first session for chrome? Or you want to allow second login by invalidating 1st session?

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi I want the second login to go through with logging out the first session, so the user has always only one session

Comment: any ideas to achieve this  ?